# How to get a component type so I can use it in a typescript interface - Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm just trying to setup an array of components so I can do some dynamic component switching later. But I'm stuck at getting Typescript to work with it and no matter what way I ask the question online all the previous answers are all about completely different things.

I've provided a screenshot of what I want to do. I want to be able to write a typescript interface and give it some type which corresponds to any vue component I pass. It just needs to make sure that it's a vue component being passed, I don't care what component it is. I basically need a vue component type definition. How do I do that?

[image: example of what I want]

Comment: Try to hover a vue component and read what type the component is, then try to use it

Comment: First thing I tried. But Im not getting a whole lot out of it. Tried using ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor. But im not sure where to import it from or if its even right to use. Heres the text it gives me when hovering:

const Navigation: ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<{
    $: ComponentInternalInstance;
    $data: {};
    $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<{} & {} & {}> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>;
    ... 10 more ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Component` is indeed the correct type, as you've attempted, but you need to import it before use:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Component } from 'vue'
⋮
interface Props {
  header?: Component
  body?: Component
  footer?: Component
}

const fragments: Props = {
  header: FragProfile,
  body: FragSubject,
  footer: TypeSection
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/Wz5lEm)

Answer (score 0):

there are another question:
vue3+TSX

1. `import { type Component} from 'vue';`
2. I use expose(vue3) to provide function fn to father component
3. use TS type `const refComponent = ref<Component>()`
   but when I call `fn` form childComponent, there show a error `Property fn does not exist on type 'Component'.`
   `refComponent.value?.fn()`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35451369)